# Default box shadow color?

Tags: css, webkit, mozilla, box-shadow

What color do the *box-shadows default to if none is specified?

```
-webkit-box-shadow: 4px 4px 5px;
-moz-box-shadow: 4px 4px 5px;
box-shadow: 4px 4px 5px;
```

How can I set that color **separately**? (According to [Is there a 'box-shadow-color' property?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3012899/box-shadow-is-there-a-box-shadow-color) there isn't a thing such as *box-shadow-color ...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/css/box-shadow

> `<color>` (optional)
>       See `<color>` values for possible keywords and notations.
>       If not specified, the color depends on the browser. In Gecko
>   (Firefox), the value of the `color`
>   property is used. WebKit's shadow is
>   transparent and therefore useless if
>   `<color>` is omitted.

You can only set the color *inside* `box-shadow`, for example:

```
box-shadow: 4px 4px 5px #ccc;
```

You simply can't set it separately, because as you pointed out, no `box-shadow-color` property exists.

Comment: Too bad webkit doesn't default to color or some other property...

Answer (score 1):

While there isn't a `box-shadow-color` property yet, `box-shadow` defaults to `color`, just like `border` does.

In practice, you have to change the `color` property and leave `box-shadow` without a color:

```
box-shadow: 1px 2px 3px;
color: #a00;'
```

Check out the [demo](http://dabblet.com/gist/3587418)

Support:

- Safari 6+
- Chrome 20+ (at least)
- Firefox 13+ (at least)
- (IE not tested)