# Change direction of existing CSS shadow

Tags: css, shadow, inheritance

I have the following CSS shadow:

```
box-shadow:green 0 1px 3px;
```

Now, if I want to change only the *direction* of the shadow, I tried:

```
box-shadow:inherit 2px 0 inherit;
```

But this does not work unfortunately. Also it doesn't look like there are additional properties available like:

```
box-shadow-direction:2px 0;
```

Or

```
box-shadow-color:inherit;
```

---

**How can the direction be changed without changing the color or strength?**

Comment: this might help http://css3gen.com/box-shadow/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of I know there is no sub-attribute like `background-repeat`, `margin-left`, `border-bottom` for `box-shadow`, `text-shadow` **CSS3** attributes. For more details, please refer: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#box-shadow .

> The ‘box-shadow’ property attaches one or more drop-shadows to the
>   box. The property is a comma-separated list of shadows, each specified
>   by 2-4 length values, an optional color, and an optional ‘inset’
>   keyword. Omitted lengths are 0; omitted colors are a UA-chosen color.
>
> Where
>
> `<shadow> = inset? && [ <length>{2,4} && <color>? ]`

So, you can't give a sub-attribute like `box-shadow-direction:2px 0;` after defining `box-shadow` to an HTML element until it or similar sub-attribute came to live in next versions of CSS.

Comment: Thank you. And the "inherit" (`box-shadow:inherit 2px 0 inherit;`) method probably also does not work in any other way?

Comment: First inherit won't work as for what or from which needed to be inherited? inset or x direction value? color also not getting inherited from parent. See http://jsbin.com/ahOcUmIs/1/edit

Answer (score 3):

A box shadow is defined like this: x y blur spread color.

So if you want to move your box shadow, change your x and y.

```
box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #000;
```

This code creates a black box shadow that is positioned 10px from the top and left. (Note that I didn't have to specify the spread amount.)

Comment: OK, but you defined the color again. I want to keep/inherit the existing color...

Comment: @SimonFerndriger my bad, I misunderstood your question. You may want to look at [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3012899/box-shadow-is-there-a-box-shadow-color#10989662). It seems that a box shadow uses the `color` property if no box shadow color is specified. Thus, you should be able to say `color: inherit;` and set the parent color to something, and the parent and child's box shadow colors should be equal. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately, changing the main color is definitely not what I want to do :)

Comment: @SimonFerndriger stupid me -- you don't have to say `color: inherit` because the color property is automatically inherited... Anyway, can't you use multiple containers? You could just set the color of a main element for the immediate parent to change the child's box shadow color. Then, you could have another content element which is a child of your main element you would set to `color: #000`.

Comment: Sorry to complicated. Thanks anyway. I just used to redundant version for now.