# CSS: Fill exact background of glyphicon

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, glyphicons

I try to fill the exact background of a round glyphicon:
so that this one

[image]

looks like that one

[image]

only with css and i want the border to be any color, my attempts with outline did not succeed. border shadow cant be an option because of the inflexible color.

please also declare the browser supported by your solution.

Here the fiddle to start:
http://jsfiddle.net/aQrPd/145/

```
.custom {
    margin-left:10px;
    background-color:white;
    border-radius: 50%;
    padding: 4px 3px 0 3px;
    border: 3px #ccc solid;
}
.c2 {
    background:black;   
}
```

Comment: i don't think you can achieve this by setting the background color, because if you notice the checkbox background go beyond its border ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
@import url("//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0-rc2/css/bootstrap-glyphicons.css");
 .custom {
  margin-left: 10px;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 50%;
  padding: 4px 3px 0 3px;
  border: 3px #ccc solid;
}
.custom:before {
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background: #000;
  height: 14px;
  width: 14px;
}
```

```html
<br />
<br />

<span class="custom glyphicon glyphicon-ok-circle"></span>

<br />
<br />

<img src="http://fs2.directupload.net/images/150101/gxdavpdq.png" />
```

Comment: browser support: http://caniuse.com/#search=%3Abefore . Genius, why not more upvote???!

Answer (score 3):

You could use `box-shadow`.

**[Browser Support for `box-shadow`](http://caniuse.com/#search=box-shadow)**

```css
div {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  background: black;
  margin: 20px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 5px white,
    0 0 0 10px #CBCBCB;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: like EXPLICITLY told in my question using shadow is out of question since it doesnt allow flexibility of colors. thanks indeed

Comment: What do you mean? You can give a shadow any color, right? Have you tried changing `white` and `#CBCBCB` to, say, `green` and `blue`?

Comment: This, unfortunately, might be your only option. [And shadows kind of have colors](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3012899/box-shadow-is-there-a-box-shadow-color).