# Blazor, CSS - Keyframes Animation

Tags: html, css, css-animations

I made an animation in CSS for a check (right or wrong). The animation is actually the same, only the color is different. My problem now is that the name of the "Keyframes Fill" class is the same ("100%"). So both have the same color in the Fill animation. Is it possible to fix this problem somehow ?

Thanks.

```css
/*=========================================
    Checkmark Green Animation
  =========================================
*/

.checkmark__circle {
    stroke-dasharray: 166;
    stroke-dashoffset: 166;
    stroke-width: 2;
    stroke-miterlimit: 10;
    stroke: #7ac142;
    fill: none;
    animation: stroke 0.6s cubic-bezier(0.65, 0, 0.45, 1) forwards;
}

.checkmark {
    width: 32px;
    height: 32px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    stroke-width: 2;
    stroke: #fff;
    stroke-miterlimit: 10;
    margin: 10% auto;
    box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px #7ac142;
    animation: fill .4s ease-in-out .4s forwards, scale .3s ease-in-out .9s both;
}

.checkmark__check {
    transform-origin: 50% 50%;
    stroke-dasharray: 48;
    stroke-dashoffset: 48;
    animation: stroke 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.65, 0, 0.45, 1) 0.8s forwards;
}

@keyframes stroke {
    100% {
        stroke-dashoffset: 0;
    }
}

@keyframes scale {
    0%, 100% {
        transform: none;
    }

    50% {
        transform: scale3d(1.1, 1.1, 1);
    }
}

@keyframes fill {
    100% {
        box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px 30px #7ac142;
    }
}


/*=========================================
    Checkmark Red Animation
  =========================================
*/

.checkmark__circle_red {
    stroke-dasharray: 166;
    stroke-dashoffset: 166;
    stroke-width: 2;
    stroke-miterlimit: 10;
    stroke: #ff0000;
    fill: none;
    animation: stroke 0.6s cubic-bezier(0.65, 0, 0.45, 1) forwards;
}

.checkmark_red {
    width: 32px;
    height: 32px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    stroke-width: 2;
    stroke: #fff;
    stroke-miterlimit: 10;
    margin: 10% auto;
    box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px #ff0000;
    animation: fill .4s ease-in-out .4s forwards, scale .3s ease-in-out .9s both;
}

.checkmark__check_red {
    transform-origin: 50% 50%;
    stroke-dasharray: 48;
    stroke-dashoffset: 48;
    animation: stroke 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.65, 0, 0.45, 1) 0.8s forwards;
}

@keyframes stroke{
    100% {
        stroke-dashoffset: 0;
    }
}

@keyframes scale{
    0%, 100% {
        transform: none;
    }

    50% {
        transform: scale3d(1.1, 1.1, 1);
    }
}

@keyframes fill {
    100% {
        box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px 30px #ff0000;
    }
}
```

```html
<!--Here is actually a C# check made (a function is called), depending on whether the entered is correct or incorrect.-->

<svg class="checkmark" viewBox="0 0 52 52">
  <circle class="checkmark__circle" cx="26" cy="26" r="25" fill="none"/>
  <path class="checkmark__check" fill="none" d="M14.1 27.2l7.1 7.2 16.7-16.8"/>
</svg>


<svg class="checkmark_red" viewBox="0 0 52 52">
  <circle class="checkmark__circle_red" cx="26" cy="26" r="25" fill="none"/>
  <path class="checkmark__check_red" fill="none" d="M14.1 14.1l23.8 23.8 m0,-23.8 l-23.8,23.8"/>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this the result you wanted? If so, do not set the color in the animation, but before. Sadly there is no `box-shadow-color` property, but you can use `color` property. [see this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10989662/13248487)

```css
/*=========================================
    Checkmark Green Animation
  =========================================
*/

.checkmark__circle {
    stroke-dasharray: 166;
    stroke-dashoffset: 166;
    stroke-width: 2;
    stroke-miterlimit: 10;
    stroke: #7ac142;
    fill: none;
    animation: stroke 0.6s cubic-bezier(0.65, 0, 0.45, 1) forwards;
}

.checkmark {
    width: 32px;
    height: 32px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    stroke-width: 2;
    stroke: #fff;
    stroke-miterlimit: 10;
    margin: 10% auto;
    color: #7ac142;
    animation: fill .4s ease-in-out .4s forwards, scale .3s ease-in-out .9s both;
}

.checkmark__check {
    transform-origin: 50% 50%;
    stroke-dasharray: 48;
    stroke-dashoffset: 48;
    animation: stroke 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.65, 0, 0.45, 1) 0.8s forwards;
}

@keyframes stroke {
    100% {
        stroke-dashoffset: 0;
    }
}

@keyframes scale {
    0%, 100% {
        transform: none;
    }

    50% {
        transform: scale3d(1.1, 1.1, 1);
    }
}

@keyframes fill {
    100% {
        box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px 30px #7ac142;
    }
}


/*=========================================
    Checkmark Red Animation
  =========================================
*/

.checkmark__circle_red {
    stroke-dasharray: 166;
    stroke-dashoffset: 166;
    stroke-width: 2;
    stroke-miterlimit: 10;
    stroke: #ff0000;
    fill: none;
    animation: stroke 0.6s cubic-bezier(0.65, 0, 0.45, 1) forwards;
}

.checkmark_red {
    width: 32px;
    height: 32px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    stroke-width: 2;
    stroke: #fff;
    stroke-miterlimit: 10;
    margin: 10% auto;
    color: #ff0000;
    animation: fill .4s ease-in-out .4s forwards, scale .3s ease-in-out .9s both;
}

.checkmark__check_red {
    transform-origin: 50% 50%;
    stroke-dasharray: 48;
    stroke-dashoffset: 48;
    animation: stroke 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.65, 0, 0.45, 1) 0.8s forwards;
}

@keyframes stroke{
    100% {
        stroke-dashoffset: 0;
    }
}

@keyframes scale{
    0%, 100% {
        transform: none;
    }

    50% {
        transform: scale3d(1.1, 1.1, 1);
    }
}

@keyframes fill {
    100% {
        box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px 30px;
    }
}
```

```html
<svg class="checkmark" viewBox="0 0 52 52">
  <circle class="checkmark__circle" cx="26" cy="26" r="25" fill="none"/>
  <path class="checkmark__check" fill="none" d="M14.1 27.2l7.1 7.2 16.7-16.8"/>
</svg>


<svg class="checkmark_red" viewBox="0 0 52 52">
  <circle class="checkmark__circle_red" cx="26" cy="26" r="25" fill="none"/>
  <path class="checkmark__check_red" fill="none" d="M14.1 14.1l23.8 23.8 m0,-23.8 l-23.8,23.8"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: Yes thank you very much. You made my day! :)