# How to change only shadow color in createTheme.js - MUI System

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I want to change it with as little code as possible.

The code below can change the color, but these are long-winded.

```js
import { createTheme } from "@mui/material/styles";

const shadowKeyUmbraOpacity = 0.05;
const shadowKeyPenumbraOpacity = 0.035;
const shadowAmbientShadowOpacity = 0.03;

function createShadow(...px: number[]) {
  return [
    `${px[0]}px ${px[1]}px ${px[2]}px ${px[3]}px rgba(0,0,0,${shadowKeyUmbraOpacity})`,
    `${px[4]}px ${px[5]}px ${px[6]}px ${px[7]}px rgba(0,0,0,${shadowKeyPenumbraOpacity})`,
    `${px[8]}px ${px[9]}px ${px[10]}px ${px[11]}px rgba(0,0,0,${shadowAmbientShadowOpacity})`,
  ].join(',');
}

export const theme = createTheme({
  // Values from https://github.com/material-components/material-components-web/blob/be8747f94574669cb5e7add1a7c54fa41a89cec7/packages/mdc-elevation/_variables.scss
  shadows: [
    'none',
    createShadow(0, 2, 1, -1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 3, 0),
    createShadow(0, 3, 1, -2, 0, 2, 2, 0, 0, 1, 5, 0),
    createShadow(0, 3, 3, -2, 0, 3, 4, 0, 0, 1, 8, 0),
    createShadow(0, 2, 4, -1, 0, 4, 5, 0, 0, 1, 10, 0),
    createShadow(0, 3, 5, -1, 0, 5, 8, 0, 0, 1, 14, 0),
    createShadow(0, 3, 5, -1, 0, 6, 10, 0, 0, 1, 18, 0),
    createShadow(0, 4, 5, -2, 0, 7, 10, 1, 0, 2, 16, 1),
    createShadow(0, 5, 5, -3, 0, 8, 10, 1, 0, 3, 14, 2),
    createShadow(0, 5, 6, -3, 0, 9, 12, 1, 0, 3, 16, 2),
    createShadow(0, 6, 6, -3, 0, 10, 14, 1, 0, 4, 18, 3),
    createShadow(0, 6, 7, -4, 0, 11, 15, 1, 0, 4, 20, 3),
    createShadow(0, 7, 8, -4, 0, 12, 17, 2, 0, 5, 22, 4),
    createShadow(0, 7, 8, -4, 0, 13, 19, 2, 0, 5, 24, 4),
    createShadow(0, 7, 9, -4, 0, 14, 21, 2, 0, 5, 26, 4),
    createShadow(0, 8, 9, -5, 0, 15, 22, 2, 0, 6, 28, 5),
    createShadow(0, 8, 10, -5, 0, 16, 24, 2, 0, 6, 30, 5),
    createShadow(0, 8, 11, -5, 0, 17, 26, 2, 0, 6, 32, 5),
    createShadow(0, 9, 11, -5, 0, 18, 28, 2, 0, 7, 34, 6),
    createShadow(0, 9, 12, -6, 0, 19, 29, 2, 0, 7, 36, 6),
    createShadow(0, 10, 13, -6, 0, 20, 31, 3, 0, 8, 38, 7),
    createShadow(0, 10, 13, -6, 0, 21, 33, 3, 0, 8, 40, 7),
    createShadow(0, 10, 14, -6, 0, 22, 35, 3, 0, 8, 42, 7),
    createShadow(0, 11, 14, -7, 0, 23, 36, 3, 0, 9, 44, 8),
    createShadow(0, 11, 15, -7, 0, 24, 38, 3, 0, 9, 46, 8),
  ],
});
```

createShadow function and others referred to the link below.
https://github.com/mui/material-ui/blob/master/packages/mui-material/src/styles/shadows.js

So, I want to know how to change it more wisely.

Comment: Maybe this can help you in some way: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3012899/is-there-a-box-shadow-color-property.